# Type: Error Message: Call to a member function result() on string Filename: CI\application\models\Country_model.php Line Number: 34

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter, jquery-jtable

Please help. Im stuck. Cant get the search button working (filter) in 
jTable Codeigniter 3. Cheers.

> Type: Error Message: Call to a member function result() on string Filename: CI\application\models\Country_model.php Line Number: 34

Here is my model.php

```
public function get_country() {

    if(empty($this->input->post('country_name'))){
        $country_name=NULL;




    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT country_id, country_code, country_name, surface_area,
            continent_name, continent, population, capital_city, record_date
            FROM  country 
            WHERE deleted = 0
            ORDER BY " . filter_input(INPUT_GET, "jtSorting") . " 
            LIMIT " . filter_input(INPUT_GET, "jtStartIndex") . "," . filter_input(INPUT_GET, "jtPageSize") . ";");

    $this->db->where('deleted','0');
    } else {

        $country_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'country_name');
        $result = ("SELECT country_id, country_code, country_name, surface_area,
            continent_name, continent, population, capital_city, record_date
            FROM  country 
            WHERE deleted = 0 AND
            country_name LIKE '%".$country_name."%'"
                . "ORDER BY " . filter_input(INPUT_GET, "jtSorting") . " 
            LIMIT " . filter_input(INPUT_GET, "jtStartIndex") . "," . filter_input(INPUT_GET, "jtPageSize") . ";");

    }
    $rows = array();
    foreach ($result->result() as $row) {

        $rows[] = $row;
    }
    return $rows;
}
```

here is my controller.php

```
public function get_country() {

    $this->load->model('Country_model');
    $rows = $this->Country_model->get_country();
    $result = $this->db->get("country");
    $recordCount = $result->num_rows();
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $recordCount;
    $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
```

and my view.php

```
<div class="filtering">
    <form>
        Country Name: <input type="text" name="country_name" id="country_name" />

                        country_name: {
                        title: 'Country Name',
                                width: '17%'
                        },
                        country_code: {
                        title: 'Country Code',
                                width: '11%'
                        },
                        surface_area: {
                        title: 'Surface Area',
                                width: '13%'
                        },
                        continent_name: {
                        title: 'Continent Name',
                                width: '13%'
                        },
                        continent: {
                        title: 'Continent Code',
                                width: '11%'
                        },
                        population: {
                        title: 'Population',
                                width: '13%'
                        },
                        capital_city: {
                        title: 'Capital City',
                                width: '11%'
                        },
                        record_date: {
                        title: 'Record Date',
                                width: '11%',
                                type: 'date',
                                displayFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
                                create: false,
                                edit: false,
                                sorting: false
                        }
                },

        $('#LoadRecordsButton').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#countryTable').jtable('load', {
                country_name: $('#country_name').val(),
            });
        });

        $('#LoadRecordsButton').click();

    });

</script>
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear to me. In the `if` your `$result` is an object (the result of a query), but in the `else` you assign a string. You probably just forgot to execute the query.

Comment: I don't know Codeigniter but something tells me that calling `where()` on a query that already has a `WHERE` clause is probably causing a SQL error. Basic error checking should have caught this

Comment: I'm pretty new in programming so its always something simple that i overlook... thank you @jeroen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a mistake on else part

`$result = ("SELEC...`
it has to be come like

`$result = $this->db->query("SELEC...`

Hope it can rectify your problem...